Visa type to attend academic conference in Australia (especially in STEM)
I'm going to attend the (academic) conference in Australia, but I'm not sure if it is okay to apply for Visitor visa (Tourist stream subclass 600). I don't know if this is appropriate since I want to attach an invitation letter from the conference organiser. The mentioned visa says just that (https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/visitor-600/tourist-stream-overseas)

With this visa you can visit family or friends, be here as a tourist,
for a cruise, or for purposes other than business or medical treatment
You must intend to come to Australia to visit only, have enough money
for your stay in Australia, not work in Australia, you must be outside
Australia when you apply and when we decide your visa

I'm not going to work there of course, but not just visit either (and I don't have any family or so there)
I can't find the "conference-type visa" for Australia, so is this a correct type I should choose? I'm aware that there is a subclass 600 of Business visitor stream that says something involving conference and seminar but the field of the conference is in STEM and far from being involved in business.

What is your citizenship?

I'm Thai citizen.

One can use https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-finder to find the proper visa, e.g. with a French passport one would need to apply to the subclass 600 Business visitor stream (visitor visa), Subclass 651 eVisitor, or Subclass 601 Electronic Travel Authority (subclass 601):


In this case the eVisitor visa is probably the best option, as it is the cheapest (free). Generally if eVisitor is available you want to use that.

I have 1 option as a Thai. So it should be Business visitor, although I don't do business?

If you are an academic, your "business" is academic research, and attending a conference related to your academic work can be considered a "business trip."
